# Sci fi story from the 50s-60s about where cats are the dominant lifeforms and they're called PUTIE

Tags: story-identification

My question is about a book or short story about a creature called a PUTIE and his quest to old Earth ruins. He makes the discovery that his race evolved from the common house cat. "We're not putie, we're cat!" It reminded me a little of Planet of the Apes. I know, not too much to go on, but worth a shot.

Comment: A Google Books search in 20th century works for **"putie "** and **"cats"** turns up no English Language works. Neither does **"putie "** and **"feline"**.

Comment: Because, after all, "Puddy tat" and similar variations is a not uncommon way to baby talk about a "Kitty cat", as immortalized in the Sylvester / Tweety Bird cartoons.

Comment: I don't know the exact spelling of Putti, because It was a story read in my grade school class by the teacher. I don't remember humans in the story either. It was a post-apocalyptic story for kids. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe it was Putti. This is 'Breed to Come' by Andre Norton. Humans left Earth, and the rats and cats evolved into sentience. When the humans came back, they recognised the cats from the stuffed toys (Putti) that they took with them.

Comment: The story contains the line you mention *Not Putti but cat!*

Comment: Aw man... I came across that one in my search, but discarded the possibility. :-p Missed opportunities.

Comment: It's Sueelleker for the win! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for clinching it for me, John.