# Book about a future where humans have abandoned Earth and cats called "Puddys"/"Puttys" rule it

Tags: story-identification, books

Book about an Earth abandoned by humans and ruled by cats known as "Puddys" or "Puttys" that wear metal claws. Their enemies are dogs called "Barkers Rule". Then one cat meets a live human.

Comment: You have a nice start here but could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, when did you read this? What media was it, novel, novella, short story, etc.? I have also edited your post to correct what appeared to be some typos, if I changed the meaning at all please don't hesitate to edit over my changes.

Answer (score 7):

*Breed to come* (1972) by Andre Norton? The Putti are stuffed toys similar to cats.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/462481.Breed_to_Come):

> When desperate measures failed to control what men had begun and could not stop, they fled their polluted planet, leaving behind an epidemic virus born of experimentation. Yet unlike men, whom the disease could destroy, the animals of the planet thrived. Each generation was more forceful and intelligent than the last.
>
> I n the ruins of what was once a university complex, a vast band of The People, more highly evolved than those on the outside, sought to master the works of men. And they learned that the demons (as men were called) were not legendary but real. Then one day a spaceship landed...

[This review](http://www.andre-norton-books.com/index.php/worlds-of-andre/individual-novels-by-andre/40-breed-to-come) mentions the Barkers:

> Cats (the People), Dogs (Barkers) Rats (Rattons) and Pigs (Tusked Ones) are the dominant life forms in this area.

---

Found by searching this site for `[story-identification] title:cats earth`; I knew I had seen a similar question in the past but remembered the name being "Putty". This returned [Sci fi story from the 50s-60s about where cats are the dominant lifeforms and they're called PUTIE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/195315/); in a comment, John Rennie mentions the story containing the line:

> Not Putti but cat!

Comment: For the anecdote it took me many tries as I was SURE it was "putty", then thought it was "P.u.T.t.y" and used SEDE because search with points sucks, then went for the gist of the story, and now I just had the brilliant idea to switch to desktop views and it was in the "Related" list. :(

Comment: I tote I saw a putty tat